# How can I avoid explicitly setting each variable to False?

Tags: python, django

I often run into the case that I have to set a variable to False. My last case is that one here:

```
@cached_property
def dynamic_pricing(self):
    self.dynamic_pricing_active = False
    test = self.request.event.tickets.filter(dynamic_pricing__activated=True)
    for ticket in test:
        if ticket.is_available():
            self.dynamic_pricing_active = True
            break

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['dynamic_pricing_active'] = self.dynamic_pricing_active
    return context
```

Is there a way to avoid setting `self.dynamic_pricing_active = False`?

I have other cases where I had to define up to four variables with False due to the same reason as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` which will shortcut as well once it encounters a true value:

```
self.dynamic_pricing_active = any(ticket.is_available() for ticket in test)
```